# Div not Displaying in Safari 10.0

Tags: html, css, safari, cross-browser

A sub-menu div in a navigation bar isn't displaying on hover in OS X Safari 10.0. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rk5bmpud/1/

If you hover over "Our Services", then one sub-menu drops down, then hover over either "Risk Management" or "Integrated Services" and another menu should slide out from left to right. They do in other browsers, but not in Safari.

The elements in question are:

```
<div class="sub-menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="risk_management_consultancy.html">Risk Management Consultancy</a>
        </li>
        etc...
   </ul>
</div>
```

Safari's dev tools show that the div is opening and closing on hover as it should do (you can see the blue box highlighting the div when it's open), but the div and none of it's children are displaying.

I've tried different display properties, position properties and z-index in CSS. Different position properties allow me to see the div and it's contents, but of course not where I want them to be.

Can anyone see what I'm missing here?

**Update**

I've discovered that if the sub-menu's grand-parent div, with class `.menu`, is set to `position: static;` then the sub-menu in question is displayed. This isn't really a solution as I don't want to have to re-build it this way (although I will as a workaround if I can't find a proper solution). Interestingly, the position property of the sub-menu's immediate parent, `<li>`, doesn't make a difference.